# geom_text and facets not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Data file is way to big to `dput` but I am hoping that somebody will be able to identify my error.  Here is the story:  I produced the following small multiples plot using ggplot with the following code. Everything is working just fine.

```
ggplot(sm.df, aes(year, N, group = 1)) + geom_line(aes(colour = top10)) + 
facet_wrap( ~ shortTitle, ncol=7) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size =8)) + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(1989, 2020, 8)) + 
ylim(0, 150)
```

[image]

Now, I want to annotate each facet with the overall N.  I created a vector containing the x position, y position, and the actual values to be plotted.  So, basically, everything will be in the same X and Y position on every plot, with a different label.

```
'data.frame':   78 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1     : num  12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 ...
 $ y1     : num  130 130 130 130 130 130 130 130 130 130 ...
 $ N.label: int  1650 1456 1348 1216 1086 1035 985 940 888 826 ...
```

But, when I add  `geom_text(data = x.df, aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = N.label), inheret.aes=FALSE)` to the plot, it appears as though every label is being reprinted on every facet. Obviously I am doing something wrong.
[image]

I have poured through SO on how to annotate faceted plots, but I am missing this problem.  Would be greatly appreciated if you have any ideas -- not very straightforward to produce some data, but I guess I will if I need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431493/3897439) answer to a very similar question should help.  There needs to be an identifier that identifies which facet to print which label on.  In your case, you should use `shortTitle` for the purpose.

This is a modified example using `mtcars` and both faceting and labeling according to the number of gears

```
library(ggplot2)

xpos <- c(10,10,10) 
ypos <- c(Inf,Inf,Inf)
lab <- c(378,2,50)
gears <- c(3:5)
ldata <- data.frame(xpos, ypos, lab, gears)


ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(x=cyl)) + facet_wrap(~gears, ncol=2) + 
  geom_text(data=ldata, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, 
                            label=lab, size=1), 
            vjust=2, parse=FALSE)
```

Try adding `shortTitle` to your list of labels.  It looks like that may be all you need.  If you provide a subsample of your data frame, this would help to be sure.